# how to use relative path in java with example

Tags: java

Can any one please explain relative how to use path throw command prompt?

my directory
     `e:development/app1/src/abc` I stored `.java` file in `abc` folder,I want to generate `.class` file to this directory `e:development/app1/classes`

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `-d` option of the `javac` compiler to specify the target directory for storing the compiled class files.

In your case:

`> javac -d E:/development/app1/classes *.java`

or if you want relative paths:

`> javac -d ../../classes *.java`

Note: I am assuming that you are running the `javac` from the `app1/src/abc` folder.

**Please use `javac -help` to get the list of options you can use.**